# Flutter: some case scrollTo not working in ScrollablePositionedList

Tags: flutter

I'm working with an indexed list in flutter, I found this lib: ScrollablePositionedList, when I put the action scrollTo / jumpTo on button tap, it works but when I put it before the returning built, it throws error:

```
E/flutter ( 3018): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/src/scrollable_positioned_list.dart': Failed assertion: line 236 pos 12: '_scrollableListState != null': is not true.
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

class ReadScreen extends HookWidget {
  const ReadBibleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    ItemScrollController idxCtrl = ItemScrollController();
 /**Here, the code throw the Error */
    bc.listenable.listen(
      (p0) {
          idxCtrl.scrollTo(index: p0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));//-->Not Working
        }
    );

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: kGradPink),
     ...
          child:
  /**Here, the code work */
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                idxCtrl.jumpTo(index: 10); //------------------------->Working
              
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.tab)),
          ...
           ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
            
              itemScrollController: idxCtrl,
              ...
              itemCount: ...
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is executed line by line from top to bottom. In your case, `ItemScrollController` is instantiated but not linked to `ScrollablePositionedList`. It means that it doesn't aware of Object to which it belongs yet.

To make it work you can add the lines inside `itemBuilder`

```dart
class ReadScreen extends HookWidget {
  const ReadBibleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final ItemScrollController idxCtrl = ItemScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: kGradPink),
     ...
          child:
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                idxCtrl.jumpTo(index: 10);
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.tab)),
          ...
           ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              itemScrollController: idxCtrl,
              ...
              itemCount: ...
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                bc.listenable.listen(
                  (p0) {
                    idxCtrl.scrollTo(index: p0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
                }
            );
                return Container(
                  ...
```

Comment: I tried it but there is still the error, and also, the idxCtrl I need to put it in the itemScrollController above the itemBuilder

Comment: Ah, Sorry I forgot. You need to put `ItemScrollController idxCtrl = ItemScrollController();` out of the build method

Comment: It's better to use `StatefulWidget` here and instantiate `ItemScrollController` in `initState`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `scrollTo` call inside an `addPostFrameCallback`, this way the code will run after the build method has finished.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      idxCtrl.scrollTo(index: p0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    });
...
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, there is the same problem